# What scale is the melody in the song?

Tags: scales, melody, analysis

I was wondering if this song was in major or minor key. I am new to analyzing music and so I am having a hard time trying to figure out the melody, or how to describe it rather.
This is the song link:

Comment: If you cannot distinguish even what the melody is here, then you certainly won't be able to "analyze" it. Spend more time practicing. Can you distinguish the bass notes?

Comment: I have only recently gotten into music, and I am trying to learn how to listen better. I am definitely going to practice more, but for now, yes, I was just trying to understand if the melody was a minor or major key. Sorry if I have angered you with my question in some way.

Comment: Can you play the melody by ear, i.e. reproduce the notes with an instrument? How about the bass notes? Can you reproduce the harmony in terms of triad chords such as minors and majors?

Comment: If I said no, would you attack me and call me ignorant for not being able to? I was just trying to ask a simple question, I did not know I would be questioned so hard for merely trying to learn. Maybe instead of "analyzing" I should have written "listening and learning about" as that would have probably saved me from this interrogation.

Comment: A simple answer to the question would have been fine. For example, this melody is major or this melody is minor or its in one but has non-diatonic chords throughout. If you had a problem with my question, you could have moved on. Do you have nothing better to do than question someone new to music and make them want to just stop altogether? Ever heard of the saying, if you don't have something nice to say, don't say it at all?

Comment: You are mixing up 'scale' and 'key'. They are related, but definitely not synonymous.  A 'scale' is just a set of notes put into ascending/descending order. A 'key' is a little more nebulous, and the notes used in a 'key' may or may not all belong to a 'scale'.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - a little harsh! Of course he's ignorant. Ignorant means not knowing something. That makes everyone who asks a question here ignorant. Instead, give some guidance as to how one could determine a key!

Comment: @Tim OP is not ignorant. I am trying to say, looking at music as a matter of knowledge and logic is wrong. There is no substitute for practice, and lack of practice cannot be solved through questions and answers. It's not about being knowledgeable or ignorant. It's not about knowledge at all. It's about experience, training, skills that you obtain through _practicing_. Nobody learns music or how to ride a bicycle, or how to walk, through analytic thoughts and logic. Only practice helps.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - not sure how, or at what point, one sees the light as far as scale/key recognition bears fruit. I'm certain there are superb players out there who could be confounded even by this question. In fact, we already have two contrasting answers...  And ignorant - we all are! And don't forget - ignorance is bliss, so we're told ! If OP wasn't, the question wouldn't be posed.

Comment: I would take issue with the stance that one needs to know what the melody is before being able to tell whether it's major or minor, @piiperiReinstateMonica. Certainly it's possible to recognize the "sound" of a major scale without knowing what notes are in that major scale! And Chris, I don't think piiperi really intended to convey anger or interrogate you - the questions appear to be aimed at discerning where you are in your musical knowledge so that answers may communicate appropriately, since "new to music" can encompass many different skill levels. Let's keep it civil, all.

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry, I took your words literally. I should know that beginners say things like "analyze", to mean that they want to learn all kinds of necessary skills, whatever they might be. Anyway, I recommend approaching it practice first, and use theoretical names only when you have something familiar from practical experience to attach the name to. Playing by ear to get familiar with things is essential. When you find even _one note_ on your instrument that you know what and where it is in this song, then you have a starting point to build upon.

Comment: @Tim Maybe you didn't notice, but I didn't call the OP ignorant, that was his own interpretation. I asked about having skills. There is a hierarchy of skills starting from hearing pitches, same/different, then which one is lower/higher. Then fnding a heard pitch on an instrument, etc. There's no way to skip the need for obtaining certain skills, IMO. What is being asked here might surpass the OP's skill level. Talking about _cadences_ certainly seems to be too advanced. Cannot know for sure, that's why I asked about the skills.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - should have made it clear that I didn't even think you called OP ignorant - that was self imposed. However, the word is emotive, and I wanted to clear up its proper meaning.  With you on cadences. Although they're probably the most defining part of finding keys, as alluded to in my answer. Mixing scales up with keys is fairly common for beginners. So, really, the question is somewhat a non-question, anyway.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I apologize for taking your words in such a bad way. It had been a long day and I was just about to turn in for the night before I read your responses. In fact, I immediately went to bed after I had responded. The way I read them in my head sounded harsh and interrogatory, while you probably had only meant to be inquisitive. That is one of the problems communicating through text, determining tone is more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The song is in E minor.

Most phrases begin and, more importantly, end ([cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence)) on E minor, with E in the melody. The melody generally revolves around E.

This establishes the note E as having a sense of being at rest compared to other notes. This is what it means to be "in a key" -- one note tends to sound more stable, more at rest, than other notes.

The continual return to E minor as the cadence point establishes minor as the mode.

The other chords in the song use notes native to E minor, so even though the feeling changes according to the particular chord, the overall correspondence to E minor remains.

---

**Example**

The first vocal phrase:

Pass me that lovely little gun
My dear, my darling one
The cleaners are coming one by one
You don't even want to let them start

The entire vocal line revolves around E, but in particular, at the end of the phrase, on the word "start", the singer sings E, and the underlying chord is E minor. This clearly has the feel of coming to a rest-point: i.e., a cadence.

Comment: So just to clarify, you're saying that the singer returns to E minor at the cadence point, or when he is finished with a line/phrase?

Comment: @Chris I saying that each line/phrase ends in a cadence in which the singer sings E and the harmony instruments play E minor.

Comment: @Chris I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: That example was really helpful - I understand what you mean now. Thank you :)

Comment: Had a quick listen, and although the opening chord is Em, as you state, when it gets to G at the end of a verse, that sounds to me like it's at rest ! Difficult to decide - as there's no dominant B going back to Em, and no dominant D going to G (at that point). However, the key sig. is going to be one sharp...

Comment: @Chris Welcome to Stack Exchange Music Practice and Theory. The best way to express thanks is to upvote (the triangle next to the answer) and/or accept (the check mark under the triangles).

Comment: As I often say to my own answerers, it's best to wait for at least another couple of answers in order to compare and then decide which to accept. Far too early yet.

Comment: @Chris It would be best to post that as a separate question.

Comment: @Tim regarding the cadence point, it's easier to hear in the verses because they consistently end on E minor. The overall chord progression is Em C Am G D Em, with D, the bVII, functioning as the dominant.

Comment: I'd argue tat the last chord in the verse is actually G, moving at the very end of the bar for the next verse's start of Em.

Comment: IMO if the OP has difficulties "figuring out" the melody to this trivial pop tune, then it's not the right time to talk about cadences. It's time for more practice. Lack of practice is not a question that could be "answered". You don't learn to ride a bicycle through fancy explanations of physics. You practice, practice, practice. Practice. Some people learn it faster than others, but the only thing you can do is practice. No "analysis". Practice.

Answer (score 1):

Going head to head with the first answer!

Yes, it certainly starts on Em. That doesn't put it *into* Em. The end of the verse goes to G, but without the dominant D preceding it. However, at that point, it feels 'at rest' - to me.

In the next section, there is a distinct 'G' feel, with that dominant leading to G.

So, my take is it's more in G major, especially as there's no dominant B leading us back to the Em that's the beginning of every verse.

Whatever, the written key sig. will be that of just F♯ - which is the same for both G and its relative E minor. Pieces have always strayed from their relative maj/min, so this is nothing new. And it's with that good reason the key sig.is the same for both.

If pushed, I *may* say the verse is in Em, and the chorus is in G...

Comment: So you are arguing that the melody is in the major scale, specifically G, rather than minor?

Comment: @Chris - hardly an argument, but the same notes are being used regardless - those of G major being those of E natural minor. Can't hear any D# to call it E harmonic or melodic minor - which would point to Em more readily. But D# isn't really a defining note - it gets used in key G, although it's non-diatonic. I hope no-one's of the opinion that a song must stay within diatonic borders...

Comment: @Chris One important thing that might not be obvious is that you can consider G major and E minor as being kind of the same key. The have the same _key signature_ of one sharp! The G major scale has all the same notes as the E natural minor, and many songs wander between relative minor and major keys without either being unambiguously "the key". It's like a person standing on two feet, one foot on E and the other on G, just slightly altering balance between these two.